# MongoDB BSON OID Failure

Tags: c, mongodb, mongodb-c

I'm using the MongoDB C library to insert documents into various collections within the same database and I'm getting the referenced error repeatedly (along with a lovely see fault) when calling BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);

I *had* wanted to use the same oid across collections -- so that each time-stamped entry in each collection would have the same oid, and that's when I started getting the error. So I backed off of that, and tried creating new OIDs for each entry, and I'm still getting the same error.

Version one where I attempt to re-use the OID:

```
int insert_mongo(char json[100], char *coll, mongoc_client_t *client, bson_oid_t oid){

    mongoc_collection_t *collection;
    bson_error_t error;
    bson_t *doc;

    collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "edison", coll);     
    doc = bson_new_from_json((const uint8_t *)json, -1, &error);
    BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);
    if (!doc) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!mongoc_collection_insert (collection, MONGOC_INSERT_NONE, doc, NULL, &error)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    bson_destroy (doc);
    mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And version 2 where I create a new OID:

```
int insert_mongo(char json[100], char *coll, mongoc_client_t *client){

    mongoc_collection_t *collection;
    bson_error_t error;
    bson_t *doc;
    bson_oid_t oid;

    bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL);
    collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "edison", coll);
    doc = bson_new_from_json((const uint8_t *)json, -1, &error);
    BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);
    if (!doc) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!mongoc_collection_insert (collection, MONGOC_INSERT_NONE, doc, NULL, &error)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    bson_destroy (doc);
    mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Both versions seg fault the SECOND time the function is called with 
MongoDB bson_append_oid(): precondition failed: bson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **guess** that your JSON string does not fit into `char[100]` and therefore the segfault is produced at `doc = bson_new_from_json((const uint8_t *)json, -1, &error);`. I could imagine that, since you have automatic string length detection enabled (second parameter, `-1`), the function continues to read your memory after `char[100]` because it cannot find the end of a string that did not fit into the buffer.

To tackle this possibility, replace `-1` with `100` (i.e. the size of your buffer) and see if there's an error message instead of a segfault now.
*Edit:* Expanding on this idea, it could also be that `bson_new_from_json` fails, thus `doc` is still *NULL* and in the next line you try to append the OID to *NULL*, which could produce a segfault.

Comment: Indeed ... the char[100] was too short in some instances. fixing that fixed everything. Thanks for seeing that. I had been staring at it too long!